# problems with integers in the python calculator

Tags: types, numbers, integer

I have 2 Problems.
My first problem is that I do not know how to write the code for integers. The output should be written as an integer ... but when I use e.g 4.3+5 it does not work ... the answer should be "simply" 9...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
Can someone help me to write this small calculator?

```
 operation = input('Select an operation (type "addition", 
"subtraction", "multiplication", or "division" and hit enter)')
datatype = input('Select a datatype (type "int" or "float" and hit 
enter)')
value1 = input('Value 1:')
value2 = input('Value 2:')
result = None  # This variable should be overwritten with the result of 
your operation later.


if datatype == "float":
    value1 = float(value1)
    value2 = float(value2)
else:
    value1 = int(value1)
    value2 = int(value2)


if operation == "addition":
    result = value1+value2

elif operation == "subtraction":
    result = value1-value2

elif operation == "multiplication":
    result = value1*value2

elif operation == "division":
    result = value1/value2



print(f"Result: {result}")
```

and here is some other problem at the output --> it always shows me the whole calculation ... but i only want the solution.

### Output was:

```
 Select an operation (type "addition", "subtraction", "multiplication", 
 or "division" and hit enter)multiplication
 Select a datatype (type "int" or "float" and hit enter)float
 Value 1:123456789123456789123456789
 Value 2:-4.3
 123456789123456789123456789 * -4.3 =
 Result: -5.3086419323086415e+26
```

---

### Output should be:

```
    Select an operation (type "addition", "subtraction", 
   "multiplication", or "division" and hit enter)multiplication
    Select a datatype (type "int" or "float" and hit enter)float
    Value 1:123456789123456789123456789
    Value 2:-4.3
    Result: -5.3086419323086415e+26
```

Comment: Why should the answer to `4.3+5` be `9`? What about `4.5+5`? `4.99999+5`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it inputted the equation as you have stated "Result:result". This results in the printing of the equation. You can edit that by doing this:

```
print("result")
```

Here is my calculator code. It is short but it can input decimals.

```
print("Calculator")

operation = (input("Please choose an operator sign:"))

num1 = float(input("Please put in your first number:"))
num2 = float(input("Please put in your second number:"))

if operation == '+':
  ans = num1 + num2
  print("Your answer is",ans)
elif operation == '-':
  ans = num1 - num2
  print("Your answer is",ans)
elif operation == '*':
  ans = num1 * num2
  print("Your answer is",ans)
elif operation == '/':   
  if num2 == 0:
    print("We cannot divide this number by 0.")
  else:
    ans = num1 / num2
    print("Your answer is",ans)
```

Comment: I actually have many more types of calculator i made like power calculator, leap year calculator, average score calculator, modulus calculator and square root calculator

Comment: if you need any of them just tell me and i will be glad to show it to you :)